# Como conectar imagens por meio de setas no androidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview

Boa noite.

Tenho um content.xml onde tenho 3 imageView, gostaria de saber qual comando posso utilizar para conectar essas 3 imagens por meio de setas como se fosse um fluxograma.

O aplicativo começa com as 3 em branco e quando o usuário seleciona um equipamento no navigation drawer, a imagem do content muda (esta parte consegui) e esta imagem deve se conectar com a próxima (imageView1 conecta com a imageView2 que conecta com a imageView3 e assim por diante).

Xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="153dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/branco"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="138dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/branco"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="212dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/branco"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="400dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```